# what does " tweak your pitch" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

But (also like dating) a lot can go wrong. If you’re striking out in your email campaigns, you’ve got to tweak your pitch. Here are nine reasons that marketing emails get rejected – any of these sound familiar?

tweak:improve

pitch:the quality of a sound governed by the rate of vibrations producing it; the degree of highness or lowness of a tone.

Comment: When you look up in the dictionary the words 'tweak' and 'pitch', what--given the context--about the definitions causes you specific difficulty or difficulties?

Comment: Try [Definition 6](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/pitch): **pitch** (n.) A form of words used when trying to persuade someone to buy or accept something. Or, as a verb, the corresponding Definition 3.2: Aim (a product) at a particular section of the market. It's talking about a _sales pitch_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's another definition of *pitch*, it's a script that salesmen memorize to sell a product.

Good metaphor, huh?

To *tweak your pitch* in this context means to make small adjustments in whatever strategy you're using to present yourself to your preferred gender.